# Simple query on MySQL Sakila Database

Tags: mysql

I haven't written SQL queries in a few years and am a little rusty. I am trying to write a query that will select all films based on a given actor name.  So given the name 'sandra', I want to select the film that is in the film table that has 'sandra' in the first_name or last_name of the actor table. There is a film_actor table that links the two tables but I cannot figure out how to do it correctly. The closest I have gotten is `SELECT * FROM film f INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id WHERE a.first_name LIKE '%sandra%';` which returns an INNER JOIN table of actors and films. This result also has a film_id field that I think I want to utilize for selecting all the films in the film table.

Comment: where is the actor table joined? `a.actor_id` but i don't see an actor table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT --- generally doing select * from is a bad practice
    f.films,
    a.first_name,
    a.last_name
FROM films f
JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.film_id = f.id --- JOIN defaults to INNER JOIN -- the film_actor table im assuming has an actor id and a film id to join off of
JOIN actor a ON a.id = fa.actor_id
WHERE a.last_name LIKE"%sandra%" OR a.first_name LIKE"%sandra%" --- if you want the first_name to only match "sandra" then just do = "sandra" instead of LIKE "%sandra%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM film f 
INNER JOIN film_actor fa 
ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
INNER JOIN actor a
ON fa.actor_id =a.actor_id
WHERE a.first_name LIKE '%sandra%' OR a.last_name LIKE '%sandra%'
```

I suppose that the table called `film` and the table called `film_actor` are associated with a column called film_id, which is the PK (primary key) for the `film` table and the FK of the `film_actor` table. If the names are not exactly as that I supposed, please change them correspondingly.

Now if you join the the three tables and use the `OR` statement in the `WHERE` clause above, you will get that you want.

For further documentation on how `INNER JOIN` works, please look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Comment: wouldn't it be fa.actor_id = a.id instead of a.actor_id?